# Html, CSS - How to create a donut chart like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a Donut chart like this.

How to create it? I am not sure what's the correct process for this.

Thank you very much. 
[image: I want a Donut chart like this]

Comment: you want to create it all by yourself with the help of CSS? or you dont mind using some external libraries like highcharts etc.,?

Comment: @Krish Is that possible with out using any other external libraries? I'm open to any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Very easy with [Html5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) using the `context.arc` and `context.fillText` commands. Here's a quick [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wm6szms3/) for you to start with.

Comment: Hey @markE, can you please tell me from where you got that Donut chart, so that i can make more customization. I can't make much changes to that and it's not showing the CSS class as well. Thanks.

Comment: The donut chart is native Canvas -- no library involved. The entire code is in the example fiddle. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above Donut chart can be done using Html 5 canvas.

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/wm6szms3/

Html code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=325 height=325></canvas>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var colors=['skyblue','gray','orange'];
var values=[47,6,47];
var labels=['Voluntary','Robot','Mandatory'];

dmbChart(150,150,125,25,values,colors,labels,0);

function dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values,colors,labels,selectedValue){
    var tot=0;
    var accum=0;
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;
    var offset=-PI/2;
    ctx.lineWidth=arcwidth;
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){tot+=values[i];}
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,
            offset+PI2*(accum/tot),
            offset+PI2*((accum+values[i])/tot)
        );
        ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.stroke();
        accum+=values[i];
    }
    var innerRadius=radius-arcwidth-3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,innerRadius,0,PI2);
    ctx.fillStyle=colors[selectedValue];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.font=(innerRadius)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(values[selectedValue],cx,cy+innerRadius*.9);
    ctx.font=(innerRadius/4)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(labels[selectedValue],cx,cy-innerRadius*.25);
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution thank you! I was looking for a radial progress bar for an app and this worked the best!

Answer (score 0):

refer this link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity
 this has tons of free charts, and with little animation your site will look dynamic. And they provide a nice feature to edit it in jsfiddle and test it out before even your incorporate.

[image]

**3D Donut Chart** 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie-donut

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code example from google charts using Javascript,

if you want more sophisticated chart you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/6xV78/)

More charts with jsfiddle examples you can fine [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut)

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Effort', 'Amount given'],
          ['My all',     100],
        ]);

        var options = {
          pieHole: 0.5,
          pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'black',
          },
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_single'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="donut_single" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but i need a custom one that looks exactly like the one i require. If i use google charts, i can't get that look i want.